# Multiple checkboxes, if checked show the correct view on the next/same page. Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, laravel, controller

I' m trying to make a application in Laravel that does the following thing:

I have a series of checkboxes with values. Let' s about 11 checkboxes, if one or multiple boxes are checked, after clicking "Next" it will take the user to the views, he/she checked on the first page of the 11 available options.

Example:
Let' s say it' s a application for a coffee shop. So you have many kinds of coffee. All are listed on one view as checkboxes. 11 options are available and you chose to have 4 kinds of coffee. On next page , after clicking a ' submit'  button, takes you to the first kind of coffee you selected. And after that the next view will occur, until you have been through all the views, from the kinds of coffee you selected.

SO what I' m basically saying is this: I have a bunch of views, but I want them to be displayed (in order if possibly) if I checked the box for it on the main page.

I have no idea, how to do that in Laravel, by means of a controller or a route. Any ideas, tips or advice how to start something like this?

Much thanks in advance.

-Edit-
Sample of my code requested by Unnawat. This is my main options page.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'options', 'methode' => 'put')) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('option_1', 'yes', false) }}
{{ Form::label('option_1' ) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('option_2', 'yes', false) }}
{{ Form::label('option_2' ) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('option_3', 'yes', false) }}
{{ Form::label('option_3' ) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('option_4', 'yes', false) }}
{{ Form::label('option_4' ) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('option_5', 'yes', false) }}
{{ Form::label('option_5' ) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('option_6', 'yes', false) }}
{{ Form::label('option_6' ) }}
(( Form::close() }}
```

Comment: How about showing some code for the views that you already have?

Comment: I edited the question with sample codeUnnawut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can separate the front end views from the backend by using Laravel as a RESTful API. You can fetch results as JSON and use jquery or AngularJS or something similar to manipulate how you display content on your views. Your forms can post to laravel and the controller can send back json based upon your checkbox inputs.

The JSON response could be something like {type1:[{coffee details}],type2:[{coffee details}]... and so on}

*Hint, Laravel has something called resourceful controllers which help making REST api's really easy.*

Once you have that json you can either leverage a front end framework like Angular or use jquery/javascript to modify displayed content on button click events for example.

I hope this gives you something to start on.

Comment: Yes, this give me a start. Thanks Anurag.

Answer (score 0):

First approach which came to my mind is to store your choices in cookie. About implementation, you could make a cookie with your choices separated by , and treat it like a stack. On every page you check for cookie and get it value, then explode it by , to get your choices. When your user wants the next page, you take the value from cookie, look for corresponding route and delete the value from cookie which was already visited.

The second approach could be storing the data in session, and it could work just like the cookie approach.